# Does Liferay provide a plugin for IDEA ?

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, liferay

Does Liferay provide a plugin for IDEA ? Or are there anyone working on this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Liferay Inc, currently has no plans to release an IntelliJ plugin specifically for Liferay devleopment along the lines of [Liferay IDE](http://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-ide/overview) for Eclipse platform.

However, that does not mean that Liferay development doesn't work well with IntelliJ.  Actually it is quite popular and successful both inside and outside the company with just the stock Java EE support that is in IntelliJ.  Also some IntelliJ+Liferay users have added several wiki pages specifically talking about this combination. [Wiki page1](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/IntelliJ), [Wiki page 2](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using+IntelliJ+with+Liferay)

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is old, but actually Liferay Inc. got a Liferay plugin for IDEA, you can download it from the [official Jetbrains plugin page](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10739-liferay-intellij-plugin)

Same can be integrate in IDEA by File -> Setting -> Plugins. Select "Browse Repository" and search for "Liferay"

Answer (score 0):

There is a liferay plugin for IDEA but that only works with the suitable version of IDEA as its not workable of the 64-bit version of the IDEA.